# How to map a nested array in React.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Issue: I can only render one iteration of my array.

My desired result of course is to get the entire length of array objects.

**Adding [key] to my rendered object fields is the only method that gives me any output. Without declaring the key in this way, I get nothing**

**Child Component**

```
...
const Potatoes = ({potatoes}) => {
  const PotatoItems = potatoes.map((potato, key) => {
    if ([potato] == ''){
      return false
    } else {
    return (
      <li key={key}>
        <span>{potato[key].name}</span>
        <span>{potato[key].flavor}</span>
      </li>);
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {PotatoItems}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Parent Component**

```
 ...
 render () {
    const potatoes = new Array(this.props.potatoes);

    return (
      <section style={divStyle}>
         <Potatoes potatoes={potatoes} />
      </section>
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removing new Array() from around the potatoes constant fixes your issue.

It seems like you may have created an unnecessary additional array.

Then you can remove those [key] references on your object in the child component and you should be good to go!

Does this fix your issue?